# MUI Select: how to force word wrap?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So I know that by passing `whiteSpace: 'normal'` to a MenuItem, it'll allow that `MenuItem` to wrap words, like so:

```
<MenuItem sx={{ whiteSpace: 'normal' }}>
    A very long text goes here
</MenuItem>
```

So now the MenuItems themselves are multiline:

[image]

But how do I make the line in the value that is in the `Select` multiline as well? I don't want the forced ellipsis (...), I want that `Select` to be readable.

I've tried passing all kinds of properties to that select, but no matter what MUI's `Select` will always be truncating the content and will always be on a single line.

Help!

Full example here:

```
<FormControl variant="standard">
    <Select
        defaultValue={'A'}
        MenuProps={{ sx: { width: 200 } }}
    >
        <MenuItem sx={{ whiteSpace: 'normal', wordWrap: 'break-word' }} value={`A`}>
            A very long text goes here
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem sx={{ whiteSpace: 'normal', wordWrap: 'break-word' }} value={`B`}>
            A very long text goes here too
        </MenuItem>
    </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to achieve this(not sure why) you can
do this

```
<FormControl variant="standard" sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }}>
        <InputLabel
          style={{
            background: "red",
            whiteSpace: "normal",
            position: "static"
          }}
          id="demo-simple-select-standard-label"
        >
          Really long text of the select label for some reason
        </InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-standard-label"
          id="demo-simple-select-standard"
          value={age}
          onChange={handleChange}
          label="Age long label text of the select"
        >
          <MenuItem value="">
            <em>None</em>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-keller-cb3wtg?file=/demo.tsx:458-1287

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
 <FormControl sx={{   maxWidth:'100%' }}> // to control width of dropdown
        <Select
            defaultValue={'A'}
            MenuProps={{ sx: { width: '50%'} }} // to control width of option paper
        >
            <MenuItem sx={{ whiteSpace: 'normal', wordWrap: 'break-all' }} value={`A`}>
                A very long text goes here 
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem sx={{ whiteSpace: 'normal', wordWrap: 'break-all' }} value={`B`}>
                A very long text goes here too 2222
            </MenuItem>
        </Select>
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve a similar problem, I used it for Select:

```
renderValue={(value) => <div style={{ whiteSpace: 'normal' }}>{value}</div>}
```